# How to generate a single coverage report with parallel tests in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, gitlab-ci.yml

If there exist multiple test scripts in a .gitlab-ci.yml file, for example:

```
.run_warehouse_tests: &run_warehouse_tests |
  echo "Running tests for Warehouse"
  python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest -m warehouse --junitxml="junit-test-result-warehouse.xml" -v
  python -m pytest ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
  coverage lcov

.run_logistics_tests: &run_logistics_tests  |
  echo "Running tests for Logistics"
  python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest -m logistics --junitxml="junit-test-logistics.xml" -v
  python -m pytest ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
  coverage lcov

.run_packaging_tests: &run_packaging_tests  |
  echo "Running tests for Packaging"
  python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest -m packaging --junitxml="junit-test-packaging.xml" -v
  python -m pytest ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
  coverage lcov
```

is there a way to generate a single coverage report that would cover all tests (or generate multiple ones but combine them into one)? If that is not possible, is there a way to only generate coverage without running the tests? For example, I've tried something like:

```
python -m pytest --durations=0 ./src/unittest --cov-report xml --cov=./src/main
coverage lcov
```

but that runs all the tests and then generates the report. Would it be possible to only do coverage (I'm not sure how coverage generation works, but I assume this might not be possible).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.coveragerc` file with this:

```
[run]
parallel = true
```

This will make each run choose a unique name for the coverage data file.

Combine the files with

```
coverage combine
```

Then you can generate reports with:

```
coverage html
coverage lcov
# etc
```

Comment: Where would these commands need to be added? Does "coverage combine" need to be run at every step? I've tried messing around with it and it always gives "No data to combine". Is there a way to do this with pytest-cov ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with gitlab CI.  When you run coverage, you will get a data file named `.coverage*something`.  Somehow get all of those data files to the same place, and then run `coverage combine`.